# How to sort a list (runtime variable) in JSP using only tags?

Tags: java, jsp, sorting, collections, tags

I have a runtime variable `${thingys}` - a collection of enums.
I'd like to build a dropdown selection list with it:

```
<form:select>
    <form:option value="" label="No thingy" />
    <form:options items="${thingys}"/>                              
</form:select>
```

But I want to sort it first.

Is it possible to do it using only JSP tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty simple to achieve.

Basically your JSP code would be

```
<select name="dd" id="ddItem" > 
<option value="0">Choose a Item</option>
<% 
     for(int i=0; i<ItemList.size();i++){ 
         Item item = (Item)ItemList.get(i); 
%> 
<option value="<%=item.getItemId()%>"><%=item.getItemName()%></option> 
<%}%> 
</select>
```

And your Item Bean

```
public class Item { 
    int itemId; 
    String itemName; 


    public int getItemId() { 
        return itemId; 
    } 

    public void setItemId(int itemId) { 
        this.itemId = itemId; 
    } 

    public String getItemName() { 
        return itemName; 
    } 

    public void setMedName(String itemName) { 
        this.itemName = itemName; 
    } 
}
```

DAL class

```
public static List getItems(){ 
     PreparedStatement pStmt = null; 
     Connection conn = null; 
     boolean success = false; 
     ResultSet rs = null; 
     List ItemList = new ArrayList(); 

     try{ 
         conn = getConnection(); 

         String sql = "select * from Item"; 
         pStmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql); 

         rs = pStmt.executeQuery(); 
         while(rs.next()){ 
             Item item = new Item(); 
             item.setItemId(rs.getInt("ID")); 
             item.setItemName(rs.getString("NAME")); 
             ItemList.add(item); 
             } 



     }catch(Exception e){ 
         e.printStackTrace(); 

     }finally{ 
         closeConnectionProp(conn,pStmt,rs); 
     } 

     return ItemList;

}
```